# Criar XML com Excel, problema formatação campo de data

Tags: xml, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha do Excel, gerada pelo SAP com um campo de data. 
Preciso converter esta planilha para XML.

Faço o mapeamento do XML pelo Excel, mas não consigo fazer ele exportar o campo de data como uma data, sempre aparece o numero equivalente como abaixo, onde a data é 06/06/2014, e no XML aparece 41796.

Já tentei algumas combinações de formatação no Excel, mas nenhuma adiantou. Inclusive tem um post aqui mesmo no stackoverflow, mas resolveu o meu caso.

Nota: Quando vou converter o range para xml, aparece a msg:
Os dados que vc está tentando mapear contêm uma formatação incompativel com o formato especificado na planilha.

Estou usando o suplemento XML tools do proprio Excel.

Será que falta alguma configuração.
Existe alguma forma de especificar o tipo de dado no mapa XML?

```
     <Row>
        <Documento_SD>3208510</Documento_SD>
        <Denominacao>DISJUNTOR DWA800N-630-3</Denominacao>
        <Nome_1>A B RODRIGUES</Nome_1>
        <Data_de_remessa>41796</Data_de_remessa>
     </Row>
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução, só falta resolver uma questão, onde a data está saindo em padrão ingles e com "-" ao invés de "/" aaaa-mm-dd, se alguém souber como manipular isto no Delphi, sem precisar fazer leitura da string inteira, substituição, etc. Ou mesmo no mapa xml do Excel, que seria o mais correto.

Para resolver esta questão:

Criei um xml conforme primeira postagem, mas com a data no formato certo dd/mm/aaaa, importei o xml no Excel, e gerei um esquema xml (abaixo), só precisei inserir manualmente que o tipo de campo era de data ( type="xsd:date"). Depois é só pegar a planilha com os dados e aplicar este esquema. Ao exportar, o campo vai com data, só ficou a questão da formatação do campo, que ficou com os campos espaçados com - e no padrão inglês.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>
<!-- Created from XmlMap.Name: Root_Mapa -->
<!-- XmlMap.DataBinding.SourceUrl:  -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
<xsd:element nillable="true" name="Root">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
 nillable="true" name="Row" form="unqualified">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
 type="xsd:integer" name="Documento_SD" form="unqualified"/>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" 
 type="xsd:string" name="Denomina__o" form="unqualified"/>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" 
 name="Nome_1" form="unqualified"/>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" nillable="true" type="xsd:date" 
 name="Data_de_remessa" form="unqualified"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 </xsd:schema>
```

Saída do XML:

```
 <Row>
    <Documento_SD>3249301</Documento_SD>
    <Denomina__o>FENIX INDUSTRIA E PRESTACAO DE</Denomina__o>
    <Nome_1>CHAVE PDWCA08-5V40</Nome_1>
    <Data_de_remessa>2014-07-04</Data_de_remessa>
</Row>
```